# IdentityServer4 Access Token and Cookies

Tags: cookies, authorization, token, identityserver4

we have a application (Angular 7 front end, .net core micro services and Elastic back end). we are using IdentityServer4 to generate access tokens from the frontend and sending it to the microservices for authorization purpose. the token generation is using user's username/password to validate the user. we have quite download feature in the app to download the pdf files. with the current model we are not able to open a new tab and passing the access token to generate a pdf using one of the microservices. what we understood is if we have a cookie then we can achieve this. so i need help to generate a cookie from Identityserver4 for the UI and Access token for the backend apis.

not able to find any documentation related to get a cookie out of identityserver4. not understanding if the cookie can be used to authorize the apis as well. appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Where you able to store the access token in a cookie?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is quite a common problem in web apps that don't use cookies. One option is to have an API that can return a single-use or time limited (via HMAC + timestamp) URL for the download in question and then navigate the browser to that URL. This avoids having to pass the token in the URL which is best avoided and limits the usefulness of any URL that may get logged and fall into the wrong hands

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. i would still see if anyone had experience creating a cookie from identityserver4.

Comment: Well typically your identityserver4 would issue it’s own cookie for authentication but this would be separate from and inaccessible by any client applications. If your client needs its  own cookie then you can use the standard asp.net cookie middleware.

Comment: thank you for sharing your thoughts. the application i am referring, we do not have a pdf files stored in some shared drive. the pdf files gets generated by the .net core micro services and they are protected by identityserver4 authorization. and we would like to open pdfs in new tab when user downloads it.

Comment: any progress on this? I also need to create access token cookie in IdentityServer4